# 401 Unauthorized Sonarqube Analysis with TFS2017

Tags: tfs, sonarqube

I setup a SonarQube server and included the BuildTask Steps in the TFS2017 Build process. TFS is an on-premise setup.

On "Complete SonarQube analysis" build step i get the following error:

```
2017-01-30T08:54:30.7388183Z 09:54:30.676  Post-processing succeeded.
2017-01-30T08:54:32.1607278Z ##[error]System.Management.Automation.CmdletInvocationException: {"err_code":401,"err_msg":"Unauthorized"} ---> System.Net.WebException: Der Remoteserver hat einen Fehler zurückgegeben: (401) Nicht autorisiert.
2017-01-30T08:54:32.1607278Z    bei Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WebRequestPSCmdlet.GetResponse(WebRequest request)
2017-01-30T08:54:32.1607278Z    bei Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WebRequestPSCmdlet.ProcessRecord()
2017-01-30T08:54:32.1607278Z    --- Ende der internen Ausnahmestapelüberwachung ---
2017-01-30T08:54:32.1607278Z    bei System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.PipelineBase.Invoke(IEnumerable input)
2017-01-30T08:54:32.1607278Z    bei System.Management.Automation.PowerShell.Worker.ConstructPipelineAndDoWork(Runspace rs, Boolean performSyncInvoke)
2017-01-30T08:54:32.1607278Z    bei System.Management.Automation.PowerShell.Worker.CreateRunspaceIfNeededAndDoWork(Runspace rsToUse, Boolean isSync)
2017-01-30T08:54:32.1607278Z    bei System.Management.Automation.PowerShell.CoreInvokeHelper[TInput,TOutput](PSDataCollection`1 input, PSDataCollection`1 output, PSInvocationSettings settings)
2017-01-30T08:54:32.1607278Z    bei System.Management.Automation.PowerShell.CoreInvoke[TInput,TOutput](PSDataCollection`1 input, PSDataCollection`1 output, PSInvocationSettings settings)
2017-01-30T08:54:32.1607278Z    bei Microsoft.TeamFoundation.DistributedTask.Handlers.LegacyVSTSPowerShellHost.VSTSPowerShellHost.Main(String[] args)
2017-01-30T08:54:32.1763500Z ##[error]LegacyVSTSPowerShellHost.exe completed with return code: -1.
2017-01-30T08:54:32.1763500Z ##[section]Finishing: Complete the SonarQube analysis
```

As the analysis finished, I assume this is some kind of logging done by SonarQube afterwards.

Build Agent is installed on server A, SonarQube installed on server B. The "prepare step" Build Task finishes without errors so I assume, the basic SonarQube Setup is ok. I installed SonarQube 5.6.5 LTS and the Sonar User provided in the SonarQube.Analysis.xml is the default admin/admin user.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The build tasks do not use the authentication properties in SonarQube.Analysis.xml, you need to specify the authentication token in the SonarQube endpoint in TFS:
https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SCAN/SonarQube+Endpoint

And here is an article about how to obtain the token from SonarQube:
https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/User+Token

Dont' forget to comment the sonar.login and sonar.password properties again in the SonarQube.Analysis.xml if you uncommented those in the first place.

Comment: Thx for your reply, it worked - although i forgot to comment the sonar.login and sonar.password properties in the SonarQube.Analysis.xml which kept it from succeeding in the first place. I'll add this to your answer.

Comment: Thanks for the comment :) I will add a new issue to our bug-tracker, having to delete the login/password properties from the XML seems like something that needs attention.

Comment: Good to know. If it's public, you could put the link here so we can keep track of the issue. Also i have another problem with my sonarqube setup questioned [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41953929/timout-on-sonarqube-analysis-on-tfs2017). Your help would be much appreciated :)

Comment: Here is the [link to the ticket](https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONARMSBRU-303)